# google-cloud-platform python client library - how do I get project information, specifically the integer project identifier

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Apparently for Secret Manager secrets, you must have a reference to the secret that includes an integer for your project instead of the project name. A path like: `/projects/<proj_number>/secrets/<secret_name>`, where, the project number, in my case is a 12 digit integer. How do I locate this project number via the Python Client Library?

If possible, also sharing how I could find this info in the "documentation" would be wonderful as I find the documentation I have to be severely lacking.

Comment: I think you're looking for this https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsClient#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsClient_get_project

Comment: And here's the documentation https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects

Comment: In Google Cloud, most things are `resources` and have their own API. A project is sort of a super/master resource and has a number of APIs. For projects, the API you need is called the `Resource Manager` API. @Puteri commented with the correct links to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, @Puteri and John Hanley . 

I love the extreme consistency of Google documentation in not giving the information you need to know to use the API. For the name="name_value" argument of GetProjectRequest. one has no idea what it is looking for. I tried the project name and Projects/<project-name> and neither of these work! The error message is also wonderful: "invalid argument".

Comment: It depends on your experience level. I read all the documentation before I work with a new service or API. My memory tends to adapt to a vendor's style and I find everything much easier. Learning all of Google's APIs at one time is not possible, but over time it all comes together. There are several tricks to use to figure this stuff out. 1) Use the `--log-http` command flag with the CLI gcloud to see the API and parameters to use. Example for your case: `gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID --log-http` 2) Cloud Logging is always helpful.

Comment: Link to the documentation for the previous command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/describe

Comment: I have 38 years of experience in IT. 3 years in GCP (but more AWS & Azure). Sure, there are tricks and I am learning them. But, why not just document that that argument takes the form of "projects/<project-name>". It would be so easy to do. Spend a few characters, save people hours of time.

Answer (score 3):

```
from google.cloud import resourcemanager_v3

project_name = "my-project-name"
rm = resourcemanager_v3.ProjectsClient()
req = resourcemanager_v3.GetProjectRequest(name=f'projects/{project_name}')
res = rm.get_project(request=req)
# res.name is of the form: "projects/<digits>"
project_number_str = res.name.split('/')[1]
```